# Hashtable to JSON in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, variables, hash, rubygems

i have this hashtable in my ruby script

```
    Table2 = {
    'Parameters' => {
        "#{splist[i]}" => {
        'Description' => "#{splist[i+1]}",
        'Type' => 'String',
        'Default' => "#{splist[i+2]}"
        },
        "#{splist[i+3]}" => {
        'Description' => "#{splist[i+4]}",
        'Type' => 'String',
        'Default' => "#{splist[i+5]}"
        },
        "#{splist[i+6]}" => {
        'Description' => "#{splist[i+7]}",
        'Type' => 'String',
        'Default' => "#{splist[i+8]}"
        },
        "#{splist[i+9]}" => {
        'Description' => "#{splist[i+10]}",
        'Type' => 'String',
        'Default' => "#{splist[i+11]}"
        }
    }
}
```

which i'm converting to JSON futher down in the script, and it works almost as intended. But for some reason it's appending an "\n" to the Default line for some reason. Like so

```
"Default": "10.0.0.0/16\n"
```

How can i avoid this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use [String#chomp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chomp)? Example: `'Default' => "#{splist[i+11].to_s.chomp}"`

Comment: The question is missing critical information: what is in `splist[i+2]` (or `splist[i+5]`, .... or much more likely, `splist[i+11]`) and how did it get there?

Comment: Don't see how that is critical. It is resulting in a string with a newline because it obviously has a newline in it. Removing the newline seems like a safe-bet, whether it be here or there isn't really relevant.

Comment: @ForeverZer0: Removing the newline *here*... works. Removing the newline *earlier* will likely result in a nicer, more readable and more logical code. (My guess is the newline is in `splist[i+11]`, the last one, and `splist` being a result of a `split`; in which case it would make more sense to `chomp` the line pre-split, rather than treating `splist[i+11]` as an exception to the rule.)

Comment: @Amadan Possibly, assuming the newline isn't required there. Either way, it make no relevant difference, and could hardly be classified as "missing critical information" that prevent answering the question. I assume OP can figure how where the most relevant and elegant place to add it to their code. I personally prefer to learn how to use the tools to fix a problem , not necessarily told exactly verbatim what to write where. i don't disagree that fixing early may be best solution, just saying not critical for learning.

Comment: I agree with @Amadan on "this question needs to have info about what is `splist`" to get better answers.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh That would be my mistake for not providing the the information you needed, still Amadan's suggestion for doing it earlier and with .chomp, did the trick. I've written a bit more information about what i did in my own answer

Answer (score 0):

The `chomp` method is used for removing line endings (among other things) from strings. By default, if called without arguments, it will remove the "\n" character cleanly for you. The line ending is likely being added by the editor or whatever mechanism is creating the string.

To ensure there is no line ending, either when adding or reading the value, append the `chomp` method to the end.

```
params = Table2['Parameters'].chomp
```

Quote from the Ruby docs:

> Returns a new String with the given record separator removed from the
>   end of str (if present). If $/ has not been changed from the default
>   Ruby record separator, then chomp also removes carriage return
>   characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n). If $/ is an
>   empty string, it will remove all trailing newlines from the string.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct the problem by using chomp as per recommendation by you guys, but i managed to add earlier in the process, by @Amadan 's idea/recommendation, to ensure potentially anything added at a later point would avoid the same error, and "splist"'s origin is from a file read (configuration file with a bunch of parameters), like so

```
plist = []
File.readlines(conf).each do |line|
    line.chomp!
    plist << line
end
```

Which is transformed to splist right after.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Note that this can be done more concisely as `plist = File.readlines(conf).map(&:chomp)`.

Comment: Was just about to mention the same. :)